# SQL table with horizontal dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, pivot

I've got a simple SQL code example:

```
Select      order_header.customer ,order_header.number_of_orders, order_header.oh_date
From        order_header
Where       order_header.oh_date >= @DateFrom And  order_header.oh_date <= @DateTo
Group By    order_header.customer, order_header.number_of_orders, order_header.oh_date
```

All it does is list number of orders by customer and dates, however I would like to make it more complex - dependant on what `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` I input - can it create column for each date?

As example, if I chose dates from 01/06/2020 to 04/06/2020 it would create column for each date and number of orders purchased by customer name:

[image: result example]

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Do you simply want SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: So, do you want to make a pivot table ?

Comment: Hi Georgy, you could put it this way yes - I would like a pivot table dependant on date range selected

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation - but you need to enumerate the dates:

```
select
    customer,
    sum(case when oh_date = '2020-06-01' then number_of_orders end) number_of_orders_2020_06_01,
    sum(case when oh_date = '2020-06-02' then number_of_orders end) number_of_orders_2020_06_02,
    sum(case when oh_date = '2020-06-03' then number_of_orders end) number_of_orders_2020_06_03,
    sum(case when oh_date = '2020-06-04' then number_of_orders end) number_of_orders_2020_06_04
from order_header
where oh_date between 2020-06-01' and 2020-06-04'
group by customer
```

If you want to dynamically generate columns based on a given range of dates, then you need dynamic SQL, which is another level of complexity.

Comment: Cheers GMB! Yeah that was my idea of manually inputting case when expression for each unique date but it's far from perfect. Issue is that dates would be different everytime I run the report and that range could be even for 400+ days, how complex is dynamic columns generation ?